# JavaScript Promise Not Returning Data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a wrapper for this [mysql library](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) so I can do Synchronous queries. I am using a Promise, and for some reason I am getting `{}` when I do the `console.log()` (see code).

```
var myq = require("mysql");
var conn;

exports.connect = function(params){
    this.conn = myq.createConnection(params);
    return this;
};

exports.query = function(sql, values){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if(typeof values === "undefined"){
            this.conn.query(sql, function(err, r){
                if(err){
                    reject(r);
                }else{
                    resolve(r);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Using a Promise:

```
require("./mysql.js");
// Create connection
var conn = ....;

// Make query
var rows = conn.query("select * from groups");

// Dump the results
console.log(rows);
```

Now if I take my wrapper out of the equation, and do it the way that they show, I get results back:

```
require("mysql");
// Create connection
var conn = ....;

// Make query
var rows = conn.query("select * from groups", function(err, rows){
    // Dump the results
    console.log(rows);
});
```

So, am I using the `Promise` correctly?

Comment: Nope; you're logging it immediately after creating it. A tutorial might be a good idea.

Comment: I was going off of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: First thing is: Promises don't make your code synchronous, they're just a different way of handling async flow. If it's working correctly with a callback, then I would suggest that `conn.query` is not the method that you think it is. Finally, without being able to see how you are creating the connection, we can't tell what the `conn` object actually is. Could you update the question?

Comment: you should try something like conn.query("select * from groups").then(function (ans) {rows = ans;})

Comment: Okay, but you only *create* the promise. The example at the bottom shows it resolving, specifically, the `then` call below promise creation. I'd recommend a *tutorial*, not just API docs with examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt to dump the results is actually dumping the promise itself and not the values: `console.log(rows);`

Without knowing which Promise library you are using you could do something like:

```
var conn;
exports.connect = function(params){
  conn = myq.createConnection(params);
  return this;
};

exports.query = function(sql, values) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (typeof values !== "undefined") {
      // not sure if you want to resolve or reject here
      resolve(undefined);
    }

   conn.query(sql, function(err, r) {
      if (err) {
        reject(r);
      } else {
        resolve(r);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

And then use the returned promise as such:

```
// Make query
var promise = conn.query("select * from groups");

// Dump the results
promise.then(function(results) {
  console.log(results);
}, function(err) {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't what I thought it was supposed to do. I think I need to do something with this and `yield` to get `conn.query()` to return results in a sync/procedural style. If you have any idea how to make this sync instead of async, please let me know! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I don't understand why would you want to make this synchronous as that would be blocking behavior. Doing so would defeat one of the main advantages for using node.

Comment: Because I don't want nested queries

Answer (score 0):

Best option these days is to use async/await IMO:

```
const myFunction = async () => {
    try {
        const myPromise = await fetch( fetchParams, fetchObj );
        const anotherPromise = await myPromise.json();
        //etc...
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```